# Setting scroll position on div tag inside a gridview

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` that there is a div inside it I want to Set scroll position on that div.
I set that div `overflow=scroll`.
I used this code, its fine but it work only for the first row of `Gridview` not all of them. What should I do ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
            var t = document.getElementById('CommentDiv');
            t.scrollTop = t.scrollHeight;
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById gets only one element, So get elements using document.getElementsByClassName instead of document.getElementById by giving class name to all of your div elements and apply your properties then it should work fine.